# How to highlight cells if they match neighboring cells

Tags: vba, conditional-formatting

I regularly work with data spanning multiple columns and need a convenient way to highlight multiple rows that contain the same value in a specific column, but I need to alternate between highlighted and non-highlighted.

For example, I'll have several rows with data in Column A like:

`700105862
700105862
700105862
700103235
700103235
700108783
700108783
700108783`

And what I'd want to do is highlight the first three rows (700105862), then not highlight 700103235, then again, highlight 700108783.
I was wondering if there was a conditional formatting formula that'd make this possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,

Comment: Is this Excel? Don't see any way conditional formatting could accomplish this. So you will have to research VBA method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your numbers are divided into chunks of *always* different numbers repetitions, then you could use this VBA code:

```
Sub main()
    Dim item As Variant
    Dim startRow As Long
    Dim okHighlight As Boolean

    With Range("A1", Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
        For Each item In GetUniqueValues(.Cells).Items
            If okHighlight Then .Range(.Cells(startRow, 1), .Cells(item, 1)).Interior.ColorIndex = 48
            startRow = item + 1
            okHighlight = Not okHighlight
        Next
    End With
End Sub


Function GetUniqueValues(rng As Range) As Dictionary
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim dict As Dictionary

    Set dict = New Dictionary
    With dict
        For Each cell In rng
            .item(cell.Value) = cell.row - rng.Rows(1).row + 1
        Next
    End With
    Set GetUniqueValues = dict
End Function
```

---

a *Conditional formatting* approach is possible on with a *helper* column

assuming:

- your data are in column A and begin from row 2
- column B is free

then:

- write the following formula in *helper* column B cells:

  `=IF(A2<>A1,B1+1,0)`
- apply conditional formatting to column A with the following formula:

  `=INT(B2/2)=B2/2`

  and choosing the format you like to highlight cells

Comment: @EricJang, did you get through it?

Comment: Hi @user3598756,
The macro worked perfectly. I had to edit the script a little to fit my specific needs, but I think I understand the logic of it. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you know what ranges you want to highlight you'd simply set the conditional formatting to be between x and y values. Comment on this question with what you dont get and I'll amend the answer accordingly.